# How to get the more than one mached keywords using regexp_matches

Tags: regex, postgresql

How to get the more than one matched keywords in a given string.
Please find the below query.

```
 SELECT regexp_matches(UPPER('bakerybaking'),'BAKERY|BAKING');
```

> output: "{BAKERY}"

the above scenario given string is matched with two keywords.
when i execute the above query getting only one keyword only.
How to get other matched keywords.

Answer (score 3):

***`g`*** is a global search flag using in **`regex`**.Is used to get all the matching strings

```
select regexp_matches(UPPER('bakerybaking'),'BAKERY|BAKING','g')



regexp_matches 
text[]
-------------- 
{BAKERY}       
{BAKING}
```

to get the result as a single row :

```
SELECT ARRAY(select array_to_string(regexp_matches(UPPER('bakerybaking'),'BAKERY|BAKING','g'),''));

array 
text[]          
--------------- 
{BAKERY,BAKING}
```

by using `unnest` - *to convert the array returned to a table*

```
select unnest(regexp_matches(UPPER('bakerybaking'),'BAKERY|BAKING','g'))

unnest 
text
------ 
BAKERY 
BAKING
```

Answer (score 0):

accoring to: [http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)

```
SELECT regexp_matches(UPPER('bakerybaking'),'(BAKERY)(BAKING)');
```

Otput:)

> regexp_matches
>   -----------------  {BAKERY,BAKING} (1 row)

Comment: side note: since OP has not specified PostgreSQL version.Try to post latest version of PostgreSQL's Documentation (should be http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)

Answer (score 0):

Oh the humanity.  Please thank me.

```
--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178844/get-second-match-from-regexp-matches-results
--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274394/postgresql-8-2-how-to-get-a-string-representation-of-any-array
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aaa(anyarray,Integer, text)
RETURNS SETOF text
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE s $1%type;
BEGIN
FOREACH s SLICE 1 IN ARRAY $1[$2:$2] LOOP
RETURN NEXT array_to_string(s,$3);
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$function$;

--SELECT aaa((ARRAY(SELECT unnest(regexp_matches('=If(If(E_Reports_@ >=1, DMT(E_Date_R1_@, DateShift),0)', '(\w+_@)|([0-9]+)','g'))::TEXT)),1,',')
--select (array[1,2,3,4,5,6])[2:5];
SELECT aaa(array_remove(Array(SELECT unnest(regexp_matches('=If(If(E_Reports_@ >=1, DMT(E_Date_R1_@, DateShift),0)', '(\w+_@)|([0-9]+)','g'))::TEXT), Null),3,',')
```