# Get second match from regexp_matches results

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a `name` column which looks like this:

```
'1234567 - 7654321 - some - more - text'
```

I need to get a string `"7654321"`. I am stuck with the following:

```
SELECT regexp_matches('1234567 - 7654321 - some - more - text', '\d+', 'g');

regexp_matches
----------------
{1234567}
{7654321}

(2 rows)
```

How do I what I want? Maybe there's a better option than `regexp_matches` - gladly will consider. Thx!

Comment: Try`SELECT regexp_matches('1234567 - 7654321 - some - more - text', '-\s*(\d+) -');`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good one! But returns an array

Comment: What about `SELECT substring('1234567 - 7654321 - some - more - text', '- (\d+) -');`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works in console but when I try to use for what I need it (setting value of new column) it does not work setting null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('1234567 - 7654321 - some - more - text', '^\d+[^\d]+(\d+).*$', '\1');
```

Output

```
7654321
```

This regexp looks for a string starting with some number of digits (`^\d+`) followed by some non-digit characters (`[^\d]+`) and then another group of digits (`(\d+)`) followed by some number of characters until the end of the string (`.*$`). The `()` around the second group of digit characters makes that a capturing group, which we can then refer to in the replacement string with `\1`. Since `REGEXP_REPLACE` only replaces the parts of the string that match the regex, it is necessary to have a regex that matches the **whole** string in order to replace it with just the desired data.

**Update**

If there are potentially characters before the first set of digits, you should change the regex to

```
^[^\d]*\d+[^\d]+(\d+).*$
```

**Update 2**

If it's possible that there is only one set of numbers at the beginning, we must make matching the first part optional. We can do that with a non-capturing group:

```
^[^\d]*(?:\d+[^\d]+)?(\d+).*$
```

This makes the match on the first set of digits optional so that if it doesn't exist (i.e. there is only one set of digits) the regex will still match. By using a non-capturing group (adding the `?:` to the beginning of the group, we don't need to change the replacement string from `\1`. Updated [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/318119/5)

Comment: I like that, could you explain the regexp and what `\1` flag means? Total noob with regex, thx!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I've added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Basically I want to get a second match of `\d+` from a string, maybe we can have simpler expression?

Comment: Hey, I use it in `update` query like so `UPDATE tbl SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^\d+[^\d]+(\d+).*$', '\1') WHERE ...` - is it wrong? It sets the whole content of `name` column instead of that needed substring

Comment: If it gave you the whole content, that means the regex didn't match. What was the value of `name` where it failed?

Comment: `"30100025 - 30100025 - SN - B - Activité - Dératisation Désinsectisation Désinfection - GeoLoc - ETA"`

Comment: Is there an actual double quote in the string value? If so you will need to change the regex to start with `^"` instead of `^`

Comment: Actually it's probably safer to just change the start of the regex to `^[^\d]*`

Comment: Here's how the row actually look like: `id   |                                   name                                    | status  | templateable_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         | templateable_type
-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------
 55507 | 60400090 - 40300016 - SN - C - Prestations - Cours de Math - GeoLoc - ETA | ENABLED | 60400090        | 2017-07-27 10:53:02.900404 | 2017-12-23 03:50:36.071897 | `

Comment: Seems to work as expected for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e3e91/1

Comment: I don't understand why would it not work with update query, so strange. THank you for the help anyway!

Comment: Added an update query to the SQLFiddle. It works fine...http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e3e91/5 I can't understand why it is not working for you? Have you tried my updated regex (as I use in the SQLfiddle)?

Comment: Yes, I changed the regexp to the latest you've shown but it still sets the whole `name`. I am sure the issue is on my side, trying to figure it out

Comment: How do I change the regexp to get either first **or** second match? I realized some `name`s only contain one "int" in it and I need this one

Comment: @AndreyDeineko see my edit and updated [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/318119/5) which should work for that situation.

Answer (score 1):

`regexp_matches()` returns a table, so you can use that in the from clause together with the `with ordinality` option:

```
SELECT t.value
from regexp_matches('1234567 - 7654321 - some - more - text', '\d+', 'g') with ordinality as t(value,idx)
where t.idx = 2;
```

Note that `value` is still an array, to get the actual array element you can use:

```
SELECT t.value[1]
from regexp_matches('1234567 - 7654321 - some - more - text', '\d+', 'g') with ordinality as t(value,idx)
where t.idx = 2;
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help! I went with regexp option